# Regular Expressions Capturing Groups

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am trying to extract latitudes, longitudes, and a label from a string in R (v3.4.1). My thought is that a regular expression is the way to go, and since the *stringr* package has the ability to extract capturing groups, I thought this is the package to use. The problem is that I am receiving an error that I cannot interpret. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is an example of a string that I would like to extract the information from. I want to grab the last set of latitude (41.505) and longitude (-81.608333) along with the label (Adelbert Hall).

```
a <- "Case Western Reserve University campus41°30′18″N 81°36′30″W / 41.505°N 81.608333°W / 41.505; -81.608333 (Adelbert Hall)"
```

Here is the regular expression that I created to grab the fields that I am interested in.

```
coordRegEx <- "([\\d]*\\.\\d*)(?#Capture Latitude);\\h(-\\d*\\.\\d*)(?#Capture Longitude)\\N*\\((\\N*)(?#Capture Label)\\)"
```

Now, when I try to match the regular expression in the string using:

```
s <- str_match(a,coordRegEx)
```

I get the following error:

> Error in stri_match_first_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : Incorrect Unicode property. (U_REGEX_PROPERTY_SYNTAX)

My guess is that this error has something to do with the Regex pattern, but using documentation and web searches, I have been unable to decipher it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues with the current code:

- The `(?#:...)` are comments that are only allowed when you pass an `x` modifier to the regex
- The `\N` shorthand character that matches any non-line break char is not supported by the [*ICU regex library*](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) (it supports `\N{UNICODE CHARACTER NAME}` that matches a named character). You may replace `\N` with `.`.

See your fixed approach:

```
> a <- "Case Western Reserve University campus41°30′18″N 81°36′30″W / 41.505°N 81.608333°W / 41.505; -81.608333 (Adelbert Hall)"
> coordRegEx <- "(?x)(\\d*\\.\\d*)(?#Capture Latitude);\\h(-\\d*\\.\\d*)(?#Capture Longitude).*\\((.*)(?#Capture Label)\\)"
> s <- str_match(a,coordRegEx)
> s

 [,1]                                         [,2]         [,3]            [,4]           
[1,] "41.505; -81.608333 (Adelbert Hall)" "41.505" "-81.608333" "Adelbert Hall"
```

> 

Answer (score 1):

If we need a string output

```
sub(".*\\/\\s*", "", a)
#[1] "41.505; -81.608333 (Adelbert Hall)"
```

If we need it as separate

```
strsplit(sub(".*\\/\\s*", "", a), ";\\s*|\\s*\\(|\\)")[[1]]
#[1] "41.505"        "-81.608333"    "Adelbert Hall"
```